Why doesn't webstorm/react-hook-forms tell me possible options for name?
I want to make components with inputs, but at the moment I have a problem that with the current implementation I don’t have tooltips for name, but I would like form fields to be displayed in name.
export const Form: FormType = ({ children, form }) => (
  <FormProvider {...form}>{children}</FormProvider>
);

export type Data = {
  name: string;
  num: string;
};

export const App = () => {
  const form = useForm<Data>();

  const { handleSubmit, watch } = form;

  useEffect(() => {
    watch((value) => console.log(value));
  }, [watch]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
      <Form form={form}>
        <StringInput name="" />
        <StringInput name="" />
      </Form>
      <button onClick={handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export const StringInput = <
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues,
  TName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues>,
>({
  name,
}: UseControllerProps<TFieldValues, TName>) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field }) => <input {...field} />}
    />
  );
};

The idea is to declare a form into which the type will be passed, and in the inputs of the form, only name will be passed (possibly something else), so, in the current implementation, the tooltips do not appear, what am I doing wrong?

You can achieve what you want in a simpler way, changing your StringInput component like this:
const StringInput = ({ name }: { name: keyof Data }) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext<Data>();
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field }) => <input {...field} />}
    />
  );
};

With that, you will have the autocomplete when you use it, even an error since "" is not valid

This is understandable, but I planned to put it in a package, + Data is the type of the form, which cannot and should not be written in the input component + if you use generic or types from react hook form, tooltips still do not appear.  I thought that such a problem should not exist if you use a form provider, but this is not the case, so I want to find out what’s wrong)
